# How to fix "g.aoColumns[a.aaSorting[f][0]] is undefined" errors after updating dataTables and ColReorder plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I just downloaded the latest versions of DataTables and ColReorder (primarily to make use of the new html5 data- attribute for sorting).

After doing so, I am getting this error: "TypeError: g.aoColumns[a.aaSorting[f][0]] is undefined" referencing ColReorder.js.

I have tried with a variety of options, and have set up various minimal test tables and run into the problem in all of my cases (so long as ColReorder is called). This stops the ColReorder, and anything called after it, not to work.

Debug info here: http://debug.datatables.net/ixuwih

Any tips? I am stuck.

thanks!

{{edit:

on further investigation, it appears to happen only when state save is set to true.
State save is a required feature, however, so I can't just turn it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well despite not getting an answer on the DataTables help forum, this appears to have been a known issue, addressed with this Git commit:

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/commit/77343b72cb035e1ceba387335136f010282c0940

Solution: download the commit or link to the latest nightly build via the CDN.